# Как удалить значения по ключу из первого словаря которые есть во втором python

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите. Никогда раньше не работал со словарями, как можно решить следующую задачку.
Даны 2 списка словарей с ключами name и age. Удалить из первого списка все словари значения ключа name которые встречаются во втором словаре.
Python

например

```
l1 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '32'},{'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}]
l2 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '24'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '19'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '27'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте генератор:

```
l1 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '32'},{'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}] 
l2 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '24'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '19'}, {'name': '5', 'age': '27'}]

search_keys = [d['name'] for d in l2]
result = [dct for dct in l1 if dct['name'] not in search_keys]
# Результат: [{'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}]
```

Более развернуто:

```
l1 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '32'},{'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}] 
l2 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '24'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '19'}, {'name': '5', 'age': '27'}]
result = list() # создаем новый список
search_keys = [d['name'] for d in l2] # генерируем список имен, которых не должно быть в первом списке
for item in l1: # проходим по первому списку
    if item['name'] not in search_keys: # если имя не встретилось
        result.append(item) # добавляем этот словарь в результат
# Результат: [{'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}]
```

В вашем примере входящих данных есть два ключа `name`, которые равны `4`. Ответ в таком случае - пустой список, т.к. словарь с `'name'='4'` встречается и во втором списке.

Comment: спасибо!
а через двойной for , это ведь можно реализовать?мне для наглядности.Спасибо

Comment: Все работает   но....если спиок словарей...то возникает ошибка...

Comment: Например...
2

 

l1 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '32'},{'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}]
l2 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '24'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '19'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '27'}]....как быть в такой ситуации?подскажите...4 час ломаю голову...уже ступор

Comment: @Валерий, пример входных данных необходимо помещать в вопрос.

Comment: @Валерий, словарь всегда имеет такой формат? `{'name': string, 'age': string}` ? И нужно ли сравнивать по `age` или только по `name`?

Comment: В условиях, этого не сказано, но скорее всего да. Интересует только значения ключа 'name'

Comment: @Валерий, добавил решение, пробуйте.

Comment: CПАСИБО!!!!!!!!

Comment: Здравствуйте.Подскажите, а как б например тот  же список словарей l1 отсортировать по значению ключа 'age'. Мне почему то словари тяжело заходят.Пожалуйста!!! Зарание спасибо. Или хоть намекните....

Comment: @Валерий, `l1.sort(key=lambda x: x['age'])`. Не забудьте отметить вопрос, как решенный.

Comment: @Валерий, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)